# Representation of circular references constraint

Tags: sql-server, database-design, referential-integrity

We have a database where we store commands and properties for devices that may be controlled via a network.

For instance, "Concrete Device" is an instance of some `DeviceType`, which in turn contains `commands` and `properties`.

We have the ability to get values of the properties of devices by analyzing responses on commands; therefore there is a relationship between commands and properties. A problem arises when we trying to link commands from one `DeviceType` to properties from another `DeviceType` - this kind of link is useless and confusing.

How can I prevent this 'circular reference' through integrity constraints?

---

Here is a [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/92dff/5/0) for my scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to propagate TypeId down to the link table:

```
CREATE TABLE Commands(
    CommandId int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    DeviceTypeId int NOT NULL REFERENCES DeviceTypes(TypeId),
    CONSTRAINT UniqueCommandNameInSpecificType UNIQUE(Name, DeviceTypeId),
-- added this constraint
    CONSTRAINT Commands_FkTarget UNIQUE(CommandId , DeviceTypeId)
);

CREATE TABLE DeviceProperties(
    PropertyId int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    DeviceTypeId int NOT NULL REFERENCES DeviceTypes(TypeId),
    CONSTRAINT UniquePropertyInSpecificType UNIQUE(TypeId,Name),
-- added this constraint
    CONSTRAINT DeviceProperties_FkTarget UNIQUE(PropertyId , DeviceTypeId)
);

CREATE TABLE DevicePropertiesInCommands(
    CommandId int NOT NULL,
    PropertyId int NOT NULL,
        DeviceTypeId INT NOT NULL,
    OrderNoOfProperty int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(CommandId, PropertyId),
    CONSTRAINT UniqueOrderNoInSpecificCommand UNIQUE(CommandId,OrderNoOfProperty),
        CONSTRAINT FK_DevicePropertiesInCommands_Commands 
            FOREIGN KEY(CommandId , DeviceTypeId ) REFERENCES Commands(CommandId , DeviceTypeId ),
        CONSTRAINT FK_DevicePropertiesInCommands_DeviceProperties 
            FOREIGN KEY(PropertyId , DeviceTypeId ) REFERENCES DeviceProperties(PropertyId , DeviceTypeId )
);
```

Comment: thanks, Alex. my first approach with trigger and second with CHECK CONSTRAINT and UDF frustrated me a little, but your solution restored my faith in SQL language. :)